# Inbox, Outbox delete error- Please help me

Tags: php, mysql, sql-delete

I have an inbox code for deleting messages.

If I select one single message it deletes all of them.

How can I fix this ?

Here is my code for delete_message.php :

```
<?php
$inboxbtn = $_POST['deleteinbox'];
$outboxbtn = $_POST['deleteoutbox'];

if ($inboxbtn)
    {
    $selectall = $_POST['selectall'];
    if ($selectall)
        {
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE to_user='$user'");
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
            {
            mysql_query("UPDATE messages SET to_delete='1' WHERE to_user='$user'");
            }

        echo "All messages have been deleted.";
        }
      else
        {
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE to_user='$user'");
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
            {
            $msg_id = $row['id'];
            $value = "cb" . "$msg_id";
            $checkbox = $_POST[$value];
            if ($value)
                {
                mysql_query("UPDATE `messages` SET `to_delete`='1' WHERE `to_user`='$user' AND `id`='$msg_id'");
                }
            }

        echo "The selected messages have been deleted.";
        }
    }
elseif ($outboxbtn)
    {
    $selectall = $_POST['selectall'];
    if ($selectall)
        {
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE from_user='$user'");
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
            {
            mysql_query("UPDATE messages SET from_delete='1' WHERE from_user='$user'");
            }

        echo "All messages have been deleted.";
        }
      else
        {
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE from_user='$user'");
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
            {
            $msg_id = $row['id'];
            $value = "cb" . "$msg_id";
            $checkbox = $_POST[$value];
            if ($value)
                {
                mysql_query("UPDATE messages SET from_delete='1' WHERE to_user='$user' AND id='$msg_id'");
                }
            }

        echo "The selected messages have been deleted.";
        }
    }
  else echo "Choose a message to delete.";
?>
```

And here is the code in inbox.php that has the checkboxes

```
<?php
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE from_user='$user' AND from_delete='0' ORDER BY id DESC");
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);

if ($numrows != 0)
    {
    echo "<form action='delete_message.php' method='POST'>";
    echo "<div class='messages'>
        <div class='leftside'><input type='checkbox' name='selectall'><input type='submit' name='deleteoutbox' value='Delete' class'button'></div>
        <div class='rightside'>Date</div>
        Subject And Message
        <div class='clear'></div>
        <hr>
        </div>";
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
        {
        $msg_id = $row['id'];
        $msg_to_user = $row['to_user'];
        $msg_to_id = $row['to_id'];
        $msg_from_user = $row['from_user'];
        $msg_from_id = $row['from_id'];
        $msg_subject = $row['subject'];
        $content = nl2br($row['content']);
        $msg_date = $row['date'];
        $msg_from_delete = $row['from_delete'];
        $msg_to_delete = $row['to_delete'];
        if (!$msg_from_delete)
            {
            echo "<div class='messages'>";
            echo "<div class='leftside'>
        <input type='checkbox' name='cb$msg_id' value='$msg_id'>
        <a href='profile.php?id=$msg_to_id' target='_blank'>$msg_to_user</a>
        </div>";
            echo "<div class='rightside'>$msg_date</div>";
            echo "<div id='center' style='margin-left:150px; margin-right:150px;'>

        <span class='toggle'><a href='#' onClick='return false'>$msg_subject</a></span>
        <div class='hiddenDiv'>
        <br /><hr>
        <b>$smiles </b>
        <br /><br />


        </div>
        </div>";
            echo "<div class='clear'>";
            echo "<br /><br /><hr>";
            echo "</div></div>";
            }
        }

    echo "</form>";
    }
  else echo "You Have No Messages In Your Outbox"
?>
```

Then for the inbox messages it is the same as the outbox but in the inbox form.

How can I fix this ?

Comment: Input Output elements on the forms are missed

Comment: What do you mean? Where would they go?

Comment: they're definitely on Alaska 100%

Comment: What?!??? please can you explain clearly.

Comment: There are several things wrong with your code. First, in the `else` block, you are fetching from the messages table, in the `while` loop you are checking that `id` against `$_POST` which is wrong. What you should ideally be doing is, use a foreach loop to iterate through the checked `ids` and update. Where are you getting the `$user` from anyway? You should also check which part of your `if` block is actually being executed.

Comment: $user is a session that stores the currently logged in users username. I am still confused as to what you mean. Could you possibly put the solution as an answer so I can mark it correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below code is for `outbox.php` since that's what you have pasted.

First, change your checkbox from:

```
<input type='checkbox' name='cb$msg_id' value='$msg_id'>
```

To something like:

```
<input type='checkbox' name='outbox_ids[]' value='$msg_id'>
```

And the `elseif` for the `outbox` will be:

```
elseif ($outboxbtn)
    {
    $selectall = $_POST['selectall'];
    if ($selectall)
        {
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE from_user='$user'");
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
            {
            mysql_query("UPDATE messages SET from_delete='1' WHERE from_user='$user'");
            }

        echo "All messages have been deleted.";
        }
      else
        {
          if(isset($_POST['outbox_ids']){
            $outbox_msg_ids = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $_POST['outbox_ids']);
            //all the checked msg id are now stored in $outbox_msg_ids,
            //we will loop through the values and pass it to the update query
            foreach($outbox_msg_ids as $msg_id){
              mysql_query("UPDATE messages SET from_delete='1' WHERE to_user='$user' AND id='$msg_id'");
            }
            echo "The selected messages have been deleted.";
          } //isset if block ends
        }
    }
```

#### Note:

[**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: Using this for inbox: http://pastebin.com/xpYdVZcA

I get these errors: http://gyazo.com/461b70a4700a5b5c3ce579fe29bda4a8.png


Any idea??/

Comment: @user3474238 Did you change the name of `input` for inbox.php?

Comment: Yes it is: <input type='checkbox' name='inbox_ids[]' value='$msg_id'>

Comment: @user3474238 Can you do a `print_r($_POST['inbox_ids']);` before the `array_map()` statement and see if it outputs anything?

Comment: Nothing. I put that code before the array map line but there was no difference.

Comment: @user3474238 It's probably because you are not selecting any message to delete. So when nothing is checked, it throws the error. I have edited to code to check if anything has been set.

Comment: Ok, I added that with an error but the error displayed even when I selected messages

Comment: @user3474238 Could you please paste the result of `print_r($_POST['inbox_ids']);` again after you have selected messages?

Comment: @user3474238 Something is not right with your HTML. Could you do a pastebin of your HTML? :3

Comment: Sure, here is what I used for the check box: http://pastebin.com/XE2FAnPy

And here is the inbox code again: http://pastebin.com/BPw6QVNu

Comment: @user3474238 You need to check whether the inputs are closed inside `<form>` tags and whether the `submit` button name is `name='deleteinbox'`. Btw you are missing a `{` after `else` before the `isset` line. And there is a repeating `{` after the `isset` line.

Comment: That solved it but there is another problem. It won't delete multiple messages, just do first one I selected.

This is what the print_r($_POST['inbox_ids']); printed "Array ( [0] => 161 )"

Comment: ??? When I did that code, it only deleted one message instead of all the ones I selected. The print thing that was added earlier only showed: Array ( [0] => 161 )

Comment: @user3474238 That isn't supposed to happen. Could you do a paste bin of your complete `inbox.php`?

Comment: The entire thing is massive, here is the entire part of the inbox part: http://pastebin.com/cXEmiEkP

Comment: @user3474238 The comments is getting long. Please click on **[this link](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50352/extended-chat)** to join a chatroom.